# React Mentions TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

I have recently installed the react-rails gem to replace an old react integration inside of my rails app.

But it seems like it broke the "react-mentions" package in production. It still works fine in my local dev environnement.

When I try to access the page with my react-mention input, it throws this error in my console :

```
TypeError: can't access property "style", _types.PropTypes is undefined
    getWrappedComponent webpack:///./node_modules/substyle/lib/defaultStyle.js?:216
    render webpack:///./node_modules/substyle/lib/defaultStyle.js?:196
    React 7
    unstable_runWithPriority webpack:///./node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.production.min.js?:311
    React 5
    _rollbar_wrapped https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rollbar.js/2.4.6/rollbar.min.js:1
    o https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rollbar.js/2.4.6/rollbar.min.js:2
    React 10
    unstable_runWithPriority webpack:///./node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler.production.min.js?:311
    React 6

.....
```

These are the dependencies of my package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/compatible": "^1.0.2",
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.4.4",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.9.4",
    "@blueprintjs/core": "^3.19.1",
    "@blueprintjs/datetime": "^3.14.0",
    "@blueprintjs/icons": "^3.11.0",
    "@blueprintjs/select": "^3.11.1",
    "@blueprintjs/table": "^3.8.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.5.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "@nivo/line": "^0.59.3",
    "@rails/webpacker": "^5.1.1",
    "antd": "^4.3.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.24",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "dom-to-image-improved": "^2.8.0",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "numeral": "^2.0.6",
    "papaparse": "^5.1.0",
    "postcss-cssnext": "^3.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dropdown-tree-select": "^2.1.1",
    "react-highlight-words": "^0.16.0",
    "react-mentions": "^3.3.1",
    "react-orgchart": "^1.0.5",
    "react-render-html": "^0.6.0",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-select": "^3.0.8",
    "react-simple-maps": "^0.12.1",
    "react-step-wizard": "^5.3.0",
    "react-stepzilla": "^6.0.2",
    "react-twitter-embed": "^3.0.3",
    "react_ujs": "^2.6.1",
    "recharts": "^1.8.5",
    "select2": "^4.0.12",
    "url-search-params-polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "^3.0.0"
  },
```

How can I fix this issue ? I'm not sure what I'm missing!